# Move qed sign to bottom of centered tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

The following code produces this output
[image]

How can I place the qed sign at the bottom line, without moving the `$P(X)=$` from the vertical center?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        something something something\\

        $P(X)=$\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
        \node (1) at (0,0){$1$};
        \node (2) at (-2,-1){$2$};
        \node (3) at (0,-1){$3$};
        \node (4) at (2,-1){$4$};
        \node (5) at (-2,-2){$5$};
        \node (6) at (0,-2){$6$};
        \node (7) at (2,-2){$7$};
        \node (8) at (0,-3){$8$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add \raisebox{\height}{...} around the whole line.

Comment: It works! Will you write it as an answer? :)

Comment: Actually, \depth would be more accurate.  \height is the distance from the top to the baseline, while \depth is the distance from the bottom to the baseline.  In this case they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\raisebox` to lower the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        something something something\\

        \raisebox{\depth}{%
        $P(X)=$\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
        \node (1) at (0,0){$1$};
        \node (2) at (-2,-1){$2$};
        \node (3) at (0,-1){$3$};
        \node (4) at (2,-1){$4$};
        \node (5) at (-2,-2){$5$};
        \node (6) at (0,-2){$6$};
        \node (7) at (2,-2){$7$};
        \node (8) at (0,-3){$8$};
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange way to write an matrix. What is wrong with this simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
       something something something\\
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{1cm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
P(X) = \begin{matrix}
    &   1   &           \\
2   &   3   &   4       \\
5   &   6   &   7       \\
    &   8   &           \\
        \end{matrix}
\]
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What I have is not a matrix. What I posted is just a reduced version of what I have, that is indeed kind of a graph (with also the edges connecting the nodes and such).

Comment: But on the end this form one sort of matrix ... maybe would be worth to see `matrix` library in TikZ. Positioning of nodes is simpler and has all TikZ features.